# How can I capture the output of a program without having the shell expand it?

Tags: shell, tcsh

Consider the following two tcsh scripts.

script1:

```
setenv MYVAR `echo "str"
```

script2:

```
setenv MYVAR `echo "str*"`
```

The first completes without error. The second gets a "no match" error because the shell can't find any files matching "str*". How can I avoid the error in this case so that the content of MVAR is "str*"?

Note that I could eliminate the backticks and echo here. This is an abstraction of a problem that I've been trying to debug in another context where it cannot be trivially removed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the backticks. This is harder than it sounds, because tcsh doesn't let you nest double quotes.

You can either rewrite your query so it'll fit in double quotes:

```
setenv MYVAR "`echo "\""str*"\""`"
```

or take advantage of multiple types of quotes:

```
setenv MYVAR "`echo 'str*'`"
```

or follow twalberg's suggestion and use a better shell.

Comment: I just sourced an empty file with just that one line. I am not getting "(no output)" but definitely getting that error, using tcsh 6.14.00. I haven't found any amount of quotes or ":q" to help :(

Comment: @balor123 I retagged your question `tcsh` and updated the answer for tcsh instead of csh.

Answer (score 0):

In tcsh, more often than not, you want to perform "special" operations (backticks, variable replacement, etc.) inside double-quotes (`"..."`) (but not single-quotes, which disables most of the magic).

In your case, you'd need to use double-quotes in both variable-assignment and variable-replacement.

```
% setenv AA "`echo 'str*'`"
% echo "$AA"
str*
```

In the first line, we avoid the `*`-expansion by using the single-quotes. We could also escape the `*` with a backslash `\` (as in @twalberg's answer) and drop the single-quotes. (In general we could have also used double-quotes, but in this case they would clash with the outer double-quotes).

Then, as I already said, we use double-quotes around the `setenv` expression, and around the variable-replacement in the second line.

---

*And yes, society wants you to think you're a terrible human being for using tcsh. It's just one of those things society enjoys doing.*